# Audi A6 2.4L 99 - randomly sets off brake warning lights, no abs, no rpm, no A/C

Tags: electrical, oil, audi, warning-light, abs

Randomly while driving or standing still I get a bunch of warning lights that come on, beep and blink. Sometimes it lasts a few minutes, sometimes it will stay on for a few days of driving and turning the car on and off. I also loose the rpm gauge when this happens and the A/C stops blowing cold air.

[image]

I have read that it might be the ABS module, but I would like some more feedback on what I should look at. I have of course checked fluids and decided to change the oil as well since it was time.

How hard would it be to fix myself? I have tools and I have worked on cars before, I also have a good friend (truck driver) who can help but he was unsure as to what the problem is.

Comment: This (rarely) happens to me. I drive an A6C6 '05, but only after I stall it. Let's say I stall it at a light, and turn it on quickly and drive away. However this goes away after a minute or so. - Try to check for any faulty wiring or short circuits

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I see multiple things going dead and the gauges stop working like you stated, the first thing I think of is some sort of grounding issue. Hard to diagnose ... even harder to track down.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer as to why this is happening would be a problem either with the electronics, or with the dashboard itself. If I remember correctly, vehicles from this manufacturer and age relied on several different electronic control units (ECUs) that worked pretty much independently from each other, so it would seem strange that they would decide to go on the blink all at the same time. This can be checked if you have access to a diagnostic computer. Perhaps a friend at a garage could help?

On the other hand, the dashboard lights going off at the same time as the aircon seems to point to a problem behind the dash itself. The dash can get a little complex to get off, but if you do go down this path I would be taking a close look at the various connectors, specifically those wire trusses connected to the instrument block and passing nearby the aircon controls.

Hope this helps.